# Scrapy paused for a few minutes

Tags: python, scrapy

As you can see in logs I have some pause. Before `23:31:45` scrapy scraped 31 pages in almost 20 seconds, but then he made a pause from `23:31:45` to `23:33:34` and continued his work in normal mode.

How can I fix this or give more information about this problem?

#### Some settings

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16

# Enabled only for check logs
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 0
```

#### Logging

```
23:31:44 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: None | conc: 4 | delay:    0 ms (+0) | latency: 1279 ms | size: 43041 bytes
23:31:45 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: None | conc: 4 | delay:    0 ms (+0) | latency:  798 ms | size: 10563 bytes
23:32:20 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 31 pages (at 31 pages/min), scraped 2057 items (at 2057 items/min)
23:33:20 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 31 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 2057 items (at 0 items/min)
23:33:34 [scrapy.extensions.throttle] INFO: slot: None | conc: 3 | delay:    0 ms (+0) | latency:  407 ms | size:   438 bytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be because scrapy is failing all requests, then it will be default retry three times, which will slow things down. The server you are scraping might be throttling your requests. What status code did your requests receive from the server? If you got 429 Error then you might send to many requests.

**Edit**

Try adding `DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT` in settings.py, the default value is 3 minutes which means scrapy can wait a long time for the server to timeout. Try setting to a smaller value. [Scrapy docs download_timeout](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-timeout)

Comment: I have middleware which rotate proxy every request. I thought problem in this middleware, but then I readed all codes of package and tried to use other packages for proxi, and always have this problem. But realy the server which I scrape sometimes send 429 code, but my middleware will rotate proxy in this case and after working I don't see 429 codes in stats.

Comment: Yes, it helped me. I checked all the options of settings and didn't see this param.